# Converting gremlin query from gremlin console to Bytecode

Tags: tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I am trying to convert gremlin query received from gremlin console to bytecode in order to extract `StepInstructions`. I am using the below code to do that but it looks hacky and ugly to me. Is there any better way of converting gremlin query from gremlin console to Bytecode?

```
String query = (String) requestMessage.getArgs().get(Tokens.ARGS_GREMLIN);
final GremlinGroovyScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngine();
CompiledScript compiledScript = engine.compile(query);

final Graph graph = EmptyGraph.instance();
final GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();

final Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
bindings.put("g", g);

DefaultGraphTraversal graphTraversal = (DefaultGraphTraversal) compiledScript.eval(bindings);

Bytecode bytecode = graphTraversal.getBytecode();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to take a Gremlin string and convert it to `Bytecode` I don't think there is a much better way to do that. You must pass the string through a `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine` to evaluate it into an actual `Traversal` object that you can manipulate. The only improvement that I can think of would be to call `eval()` more directly:

```
// construct all of this once and re-use it for your application
final GremlinGroovyScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngine();
final Graph graph = EmptyGraph.instance();
final GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
final Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
bindings.put("g", g);

//////////////

String query = (String) requestMessage.getArgs().get(Tokens.ARGS_GREMLIN);
DefaultGraphTraversal graphTraversal = (DefaultGraphTraversal) engine.eval(query, bindings);    
Bytecode bytecode = graphTraversal.getBytecode();
```